# Labels on features - ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

I am using leaflet 0.7 and want to add a static label using the leaflet.label plugin.

I get the data with a ajax call. I am not sure where to put my onEachFeature function to populate the labels. I am relatively new to javascript and think i got a bit confused on this one.

This code works as long as I use layer.bindLabel('static label'). But I cannot populate it with data from my ajax call.
I know the layer is created before the ajax call and thus not have access to the data. How can I arrange the code to populate the Label with data from my ajax call?

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
var pointlayer= new L.GeoJSON(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: sandicon});
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.id, //Dynamic label
                    {noHide:true,direction:'auto'});
        },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup('Test' + feature.properties.id);
    }
}).addTo(map);

$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'getPoint',
    success: handlePoint,

});

function handlePoint(data) {
    pointlayer.addData(data);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your label to the marker created in pointToLayer

EDIT: this was not the error

I am not sure where you went wrong but I left a working example here:

https://github.com/yafred/ajax-geojson-and-labels (source)

https://yafred.github.io/ajax-geojson-and-labels/ (web)

Note: L.GeoJSON is for leaflet 1.0, L.GeoJson is for leaflet 0.7

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you mean like this? return L.marker(latlng, {icon: sandicon}).bindLabel(feature.properties.gid, {noHide:true,direction:'auto'}); Still no luck when I tried that. I can add a static string label though. Is it because it cannot reach the property you think? I dont get any errors just and empty label

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. I'm trying to set up an example.

Comment: Thanks for the links. The live link was showing an https error but I tried your code example with my data but. The labels still stay empty so there is something else going wrong. But if your example is working then there is something else that is not working with my code.